# jQuery: Object with random placement should always stay completely inside parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```js
var vw = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + "vw";
var vh = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + "vh";
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + "vw";
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 101) + "vh";

$('<div></div>').appendTo('html').css({
  "width": vw,
  "height": vh,
  "top": x,
  "left": y
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If the page gets loaded, a random sized color area gets created on a random position.

**My question is:**
Is there a way to let the `<div></div>` always stay completely inside the body (parent), without cutting them off in some cases?

Would be very thankful for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can generate the `top` and `left` properties based on the generated width and height.

```
const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
var vw = getRandom(0, 100);
var vh = getRandom(0, 100);
var x = getRandom(0, 100 - vw);
var y = getRandom(0, 100 - vh);

$('<div></div>').appendTo('html').css({
  "width": vw + "vw",
  "height": vh + "vh",
  "top": y + "vh",
  "left": x + "vw"
});
```

```js
const getRandom = (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
var vw = getRandom(0, 100);
var vh = getRandom(0, 100);
var x = getRandom(0, 100 - vw);
var y = getRandom(0, 100 - vh);

$('<div></div>').appendTo('html').css({
  "width": vw + "vw",
  "height": vh + "vh",
  "top": y + "vh",
  "left": x + "vw"
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: grey;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```